# R - convert numeric year to date format - 1990 to 01/01/1990

Tags: r

I have a numeric column, `YEAR`, which is datatype num, in a data frame called `df`

How do I change all the  values in column `YEAR` to 01/01/1990 (class date) from 1990 (class num)

```
Have    Want
YEAR    YEAR
1990    01/01/1990
1991    01/01/1991
1992    01/01/1992
1993    01/01/1993
"       "
"       "
"       "
```

Comment: i suggest formatting it as if it were a string: `format(as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01")), "%d/%m/%Y")`.

Comment: Should your desired column be of class date or character?

Comment: @markus  desired class is date

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you.

```
year <- c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993)
as.Date(ISOdate(year, 1, 1))
```

Returns:

```
[1] "1990-01-01" "1991-01-01" "1992-01-01" "1993-01-01"
```